# USB Audio Input Interruption

Tags: audio, usb, microcontroller

A couple months ago I asked a very similar question to what I'm experiencing right now but it's a little different and I believe that question's answer does no apply here.

Basically, I'm programming a microcontroller to do USB audio recording (using USB Audio Class 2.0 / high speed USB). As a test I'm just recording a simple 440 Hz sine wave in the audio input in audacity to see if I can get a clean-ish signal. When I record this sine wave, I get a very periodic interruption in the waveform. This interruption appears in the form of the recorded signal trying to go to 0 or silence. Then it continues on normally. As shown:

Sample Rate - 44.1 kHz:
[image: 440 Hz Sine Wave - 44.1 kHz sample rate]

Sample Rate - 48 kHz:
[image: 440 Hz Sine Wave - 48 kHz sample rate]

As you can notice, with a 48 kHz sample rate the interruptions are longer. I'm guessing I'm experiencing some weird issue when my mcu's codec data goes to USB. I have no issues when I deactivate USB (basically codec input -> mcu -> codec output).

The below is how I'm calculating my frame length which I got from a USB Audio guide from Apple (using 44.1kHz sample rate and 24 bit rate):

```
#define AUDIO_POLL_INT     4
#define FRAME_BYTES        3
#define NUM_CHANNELS       STEREO

// Calculate the frame length
uint16_t frame_len = 44 (44.1kHz/1000 samples) * NUM_CHANNELS * FRAME_BYTES;
// Every 10 ms, calculate frame length with additional frame (only applies to 44.1kHz sample rate)
if (!(frame_pos % 9)) frame_len += (1 * NUM_CHANNELS * FRAME_BYTES)

// Increment frame position per usb call
frame_pos = (((frame_pos + 1) / 8) * (2 << (AUDIO_POLL_INT-1))) % 10;
```

So far... the only thing I could think of that's causing this issue is the synchronization between the USB clock and codec clock (USB is at 12 MHz, codec is at 11.2896 MHz or 12.288 MHz). I can't seem to get rid of it no matter how many framing "fixes" I try out. If the general public agrees this is a clock sync issue, I'll kind of have a better picture on how to continue on.

Any help on this would be appreciated! I will post more code if I need to. Thanks

**EDIT** Turns out I recorded the 48 kHz sine wave in Audacity at 44.1kHz sample rate. I've changed out the picture of the 48 kHz recording to show the correct sampled recording.

**EDIT2** So I've played around with the number of buffers I use to capture the codec input. The output shown in the above pictures are when I use 10 buffers.

This is what it looks like when I use one buffer at 44.1kHz (periodic; happens every 45 ms):
[image]

Comment: A guess is on the frame where you're supposed to copy 1 more sample of audio...you aren't.

Comment: also, on the 48KHz version, you don't need to have changing frame sizes.  48000 divides evenly into 1000 (so you should always be sending 48 stereo samples per frame, 3 bytes per channel sample)

Comment: Hi @RussSchultz, that's an error on my code above; at 48kHz I don't add any additional frames (it stays at 48 * 2 * 3 = 288). But I'm going to look back into it from the missing frame for 44.1kHz. But for 48 kHz it looks like 4 samples are missing every time. I'm guessing I'm missing 4 frames? But this doesn't make sense since 48 kHz frame sizes are consistent vs 44.1kHz you have to add on additional frames because it is uneven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm don't have any microcontroller knowledge, but some observations...

When I first saw this, I assumed something to do with a clock rate mismatch.  The drop out is regular enough at 44.1 kHz it seems to drop out for exactly one sample.  It also appears that the next sample is what would have been there without the dropout, implying that the incoming digital data rate couldn't keep up with the digital playback rate.  A buffer underrun.

Your 48 kHz recording though is interesting.  In this case, the zero value is approximated for a few samples, and the waveform gets wonky just before and a bit after the dive to zero.  This implies some issue more on the analog side of things.  Based on what you're saying though, there is no analog domain audio here... my theory then is that your 48 kHz recording isn't really what's happening at the low level, and something has resampled 44.1 kHz up to 48 kHz.

Also interesting is that there is a missing dropout in the 44.1 kHz recording.

I think it would be useful to know if the dropouts are guaranteed, and guaranteed at an exact frequency or not.  I think it would also be good to confirm the entire signal path here, and ensure that no software resampling is being done in your tests.

Comment: Hi Brad, so your comment struck me... I forgot to set the audacity project to 48 kHz when I recorded it! You were right and the recording was being resampled and that's why it was wonky. The post has been edited to reflect what it actually looks like. As for the actual dropouts; when you say buffer underrun... I'm probably just sending an incorrect frame length at that specific USB write if I understand correctly?

Comment: Just to add on because I was running out of characters... When I don't do USB transfers (just direct audio in and out of the mcu), I don't get any dropouts at any frequency (did a sine wave chirp to confirm).

Comment: More observations... With the corrected 48 kHz sampled waveform, you can see that the dropouts are occurring with greater frequency than at 44.1 kHz.  Also, it's hard to tell but it looks like it's occurring for a different amount of samples each time.  Can you confirm that?  If possible, can you crank it up to 96 kHz or 88.2 kHz and see what happens?  If you run the test multiple times, does the interval of dropouts change?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have 88.2/96 kHz sample rate options built into my code. It does seem to happen pretty periodically from my test sessions. However, it's very interesting to note that sometimes the recording runs more smoothly than other tests (I get more pure sine / no dropouts once I reconfigure sample rates from 44.1->48 for example). I will post more results once I work on this a bit more. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Brad, so it turns out that when I add one more frame at the end of my `frame_pos` calculation, the dropout disappears and it becomes stable. However, I still do get the occasional dropout/noise so I'm guessing this might be jitter. Any suggestions on that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, I have no specific suggestions as I'm not familiar with what you're working with.  The only suggestion I'd have is to use bigger buffers so that the jitter doesn't matter.

Comment: Well honestly that's the one thing I have not tried yet haha. Thanks! Marking you as the answer for helping me out

Comment: "However, I still do get the occasional dropout/noise so I'm guessing this might be jitter"  Is it synchronous/asynchronous/adaptive? Synchronous is guaranteed to be exactly 48 samples per frame, but async can be ±1 depending on clock differences.